# Scala - evaluate function calls sequentially until one return

Tags: scala

I have a few 'legacy' endpoints that can return the Data I'm looking for.

```
def mainCall(id): Data {

    maybeMyDataInEndpoint1(id: UUID): DataA

    maybeMyDataInEndpoint2(id: UUID): DataB

    maybeMyDataInEndpoint3(id: UUID): DataC
}
```

- `null` can be returned if no `DataX` found
- return types for each method are different. There are a `convert` method that converting each `DataX` to unified `Data`.
- The endpoints are not Scala-ish

What is the **best Scala approach** to evaluate those method calls sequentially until I have the value I need?

In pseudo I would do something like:

```
val myData = maybeMyDataInEndpoint1 getOrElse maybeMyDataInEndpoint2 getOrElse maybeMyDataInEndpoint3
```

Comment: If any of your calls might return `null`, why not use `Option` to help sequence the processing? Are there 3 different `convert` methods for the 3 different `DataX` or does a single `convert` work for the different `DataX` types?

Comment: What does it mean "there is no Option available to wrap ..."??? You are asking about "the best _scala_ approach". `Option` IS _scala_ ...

Comment: @Dima you absolutely right. Sorry, bad wording from my part. Of course Option is Scala :) I meant that the endpoint's can't return Option. That's why I used getOrElse later in the pseudo...

Comment: `Option(function)` then?

Comment: @Dima it's not enough

Comment: @Stas Why isn't it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use an easier approach, though the other Answers use more elaborate language features. 
Just use `Option()` to catch the `null`, chain with `orElse`. I'm assuming methods `convertX(d:DataX):Data` for explicit conversion. As it might not be found at all we return an `Option`

```
def mainCall(id: UUID): Option[Data] {
  Option(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1(id)).map(convertA)
  .orElse(Option(maybeMyDataInEndpoint2(id)).map(convertB))
  .orElse(Option(maybeMyDataInEndpoint3(id)).map(convertC))
}
```

Comment: Looks like the most simple and yet convenient solution. Previously thought that it won't be enough. Are there any downsides for this one?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe You can lift these methods as high order functions of `List`s and `collectFirst`, like:

```
  val fs = List(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1 _, maybeMyDataInEndpoint2 _, maybeMyDataInEndpoint3 _)

  val f = (a: UUID) => fs.collectFirst {
    case u  if u(a) != null => u(a)
  }
  r(myUUID)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the return type of each endpoint is different. There is convertTo a unified type later... editing the q. Thanks.

Comment: if for different **return type**, maybe you can update `val fs` to `val fs: List[UUID => Any]`, it will erase the return type to `Any`.

Answer (score 5):

The **best Scala approach** IMHO is to do things in the most straightforward way.

- To handle optional values (or `null`s from Java land), use `Option`.
- To sequentially evaluate a list of methods, fold over a `Seq` of functions.
- To convert from one data type to another, use either (1.) implicit conversions or (2.) regular functions depending on the situation and your preference.

  1. (**Edit**) Assuming implicit conversions:

     ```
     def legacyEndpoint[A](endpoint: UUID => A)(implicit convert: A => Data) =
       (id: UUID) => Option(endpoint(id)).map(convert)

     val legacyEndpoints = Seq(
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1),
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint2),
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint3)
     )

     def mainCall(id: UUID): Option[Data] =
       legacyEndpoints.foldLeft(Option.empty[Data])(_ orElse _(id))
     ```
  2. (**Edit**) Using explicit conversions:

     ```
     def legacyEndpoint[A](endpoint: UUID => A)(convert: A => Data) =
       (id: UUID) => Option(endpoint(id)).map(convert)

     val legacyEndpoints = Seq(
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1)(fromDataA),
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint2)(fromDataB),
       legacyEndpoint(maybeMyDataInEndpoint3)(fromDataC)
     )

     ... // same as before
     ```

Comment: This is cleanest IMHO except for the foldLeft continuing after we have a result, rather than stopping the iteration early (even if the endPoints aren't executed).

Comment: Yes, I agree. There is another answer suggesting to use `collectFirst`, however it executes the endpoint twice which is potentially much worse.

Comment: Another better option might be to use `legacyEndpoints.iterator.map(_(id)).find(_.isDefined).flatten`

Comment: Thanks, it's nice and clean. I'm a bit concerned about the `foldLeft` which will execute all the endpoints, right?

Comment: No, it will not because the argument to `orElse` (i.e. the endpoint call `_(id)`) is by-name. It will only be executed if the accumulator on the left is `None`. However it will create a (unevaluated) thunk for each endpoint. If you want to avoid that you can use the `iterator` version.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it.

**(1)** You can make your `convert` methods implicit (or wrap them into implicit wrappers) for convenience.

**(2)** Then use `Stream` to build `chain` from method calls. You should give type inference a hint that you want your stream to contain `Data` elements (not DataX as returned by legacy methods) so that appropriate implicit `convert` will be applied to each result of a legacy method call.

**(3)** Since `Stream` is lazy and evaluates its tail "by name" only first method gets called so far. At this point you can apply lazy filter to skip `null` results.

**(4)** Now you can actually evaluate `chain`, getting first non-`null` result with `headOption`

**(HACK)** Unfortunately, scala type inference (at the time of writing, v2.12.4) is not powerful enough to allow using `#::` stream methods, unless you guide it every step of the way. Using `cons` makes inference happy but is cumbersome. Also, building stream using vararg `apply` method of companion object is not an option too, since scala does not support "by-name" varargs yet. In my example below I use combination of `stream` and `toLazyData` methods. `stream` is a generic helper, builds streams from 0-arg functions. `toLazyData` is an implicit "by-name" conversion designed to interplay with implicit `convert` functions that convert from `DataX` to `Data`.

Here is the demo that demonstrates the idea with more detail:

```
object Demo {

  case class Data(value: String)
  class DataA
  class DataB
  class DataC

  def maybeMyDataInEndpoint1(id: String): DataA = {
    println("maybeMyDataInEndpoint1")
    null
  }

  def maybeMyDataInEndpoint2(id: String): DataB = {
    println("maybeMyDataInEndpoint2")
    new DataB
  }

  def maybeMyDataInEndpoint3(id: String): DataC = {
    println("maybeMyDataInEndpoint3")
    new DataC
  }

  implicit def convert(data: DataA): Data = if (data == null) null else Data(data.toString)
  implicit def convert(data: DataB): Data = if (data == null) null else Data(data.toString)
  implicit def convert(data: DataC): Data = if (data == null) null else Data(data.toString)

  implicit def toLazyData[T](value: => T)(implicit convert: T => Data): (() => Data) = () => convert(value)

  def stream[T](xs: (() => T)*): Stream[T] = {
    xs.toStream.map(_())
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]) {

    val chain = stream(
      maybeMyDataInEndpoint1("1"),
      maybeMyDataInEndpoint2("2"),
      maybeMyDataInEndpoint3("3")
    )

    val result = chain.filter(_ != null).headOption.getOrElse(Data("default"))

    println(result)

  }

}
```

This prints:

```
maybeMyDataInEndpoint1
maybeMyDataInEndpoint2
Data(Demo$DataB@16022d9d)
```

Here `maybeMyDataInEndpoint1` returns `null` and `maybeMyDataInEndpoint2` needs to be invoked, delivering `DataB`, `maybeMyDataInEndpoint3` never gets invoked since we already have the result.

Answer (score 2):

I think @g.krastev's answer is perfectly good for your use case and you should accept that. I'm just expending a bit on it to show how you can make the last step slightly better with [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/guidelines.html).

First, the boilerplate:

```
import java.util.UUID

final case class DataA(i: Int)
final case class DataB(i: Int)
final case class DataC(i: Int)
type Data = Int

def convertA(a: DataA): Data = a.i
def convertB(b: DataB): Data = b.i
def convertC(c: DataC): Data = c.i

def maybeMyDataInEndpoint1(id: UUID): DataA = DataA(1)
def maybeMyDataInEndpoint2(id: UUID): DataB = DataB(2)
def maybeMyDataInEndpoint3(id: UUID): DataC = DataC(3)
```

This is basically what you have, in a way that you can copy/paste in the REPL and have compile.

Now, let's first declare a way to turn each of your endpoints into something safe and unified:

```
def makeSafe[A, B](evaluate: UUID ⇒ A, f: A ⇒ B): UUID ⇒ Option[B] = 
  id ⇒ Option(evaluate(id)).map(f)
```

With this in place, you can, for example, call the following to turn `maybeMyDataInEndpoint1` into a `UUID => Option[A]`:

```
makeSafe(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1, convertA)
```

The idea is now to turn your endpoints into a list of `UUID => Option[A]` and fold over that list. Here's your list:

```
val endpoints = List(
  makeSafe(maybeMyDataInEndpoint1, convertA),
  makeSafe(maybeMyDataInEndpoint2, convertB),
  makeSafe(maybeMyDataInEndpoint3, convertC)
)
```

You can now fold on it manually, which is what @g.krastev did:

```
def mainCall(id: UUID): Option[Data] = 
  endpoints.foldLeft(None: Option[Data])(_ orElse _(id))
```

If you're fine with a `cats` dependency, the notion of folding over a list of options is just a concrete use case of a common pattern (the interaction of `Foldable` and `Monoid`):

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

def mainCall(id: UUID): Option[Data] = endpoints.foldMap(_(id))
```

There are other ways to make this nicer still, but they might be overkill in this context - I'd probably declare a type class to turn any type into a `Data`, say, to give `makeSafe` a cleaner type signature.

Comment: Isn’t it short-circuited? I’ll have to double check, thanks for pointing it out!